# DFA without the substring "abb"

Tags: finite-automata

$$
 L_{1}:=\left\{w \in\{a, b\}^{*} \mid w\right.  does \ not \ have \ the \ substring  \left.a b b\right\} 
$$

[image]

Hello,
I wanted to ask whether this dfa is correct according to L1.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Please don't change the question after receiving an answer, as that invalidates the existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DFA is not correct.  For example, the string $a$ is not accepted by the DFA because $q1$ is not an accepting state, but the string $a$ belongs to $L1$ because it does not contain $abb$.

Comment: Hi, I constructed another dfa, is this now correct?

Comment: @Seonix Yes, the new version looks correct.